# Apache airflow macro to get last dag run execution time

Tags: airflow

I thought the macro `prev_execution_date` listed [here](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#macros) would get me the execution date of the last DAG run, but looking at the source code it seems to only get the last date based on the DAG schedule.

```
prev_execution_date = task.dag.previous_schedule(self.execution_date)
```

Is there any way via macros to get the execution date of the DAG when it doesn't run on a schedule?

Comment: For readers of this question, also worth checking **[1]** [Getting the date of the most recent successful DAG execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607042/3679900) and **[2]** [How to get last two successful execution dates of Airflow job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61671646/3679900) or this [search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+get+last+execution+date+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own custom macro for this as follows:

```
# custom macro function
def get_last_dag_run(dag):
    last_dag_run = dag.get_last_dagrun()
    if last_dag_run is None:
        return "no prev run"
    else:
        return last_dag_run.execution_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# add macro in user_defined_macros in dag definition
dag = DAG(dag_id="my_test_dag",
      schedule_interval='@daily',
      user_defined_macros={
          'last_dag_run_execution_date': get_last_dag_run
      }
)

# example of using it in practice
print_vals = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_vals',
    bash_command='echo {{ last_dag_run_execution_date(dag) }}',
    dag=dag
)
```

Note that the dag.get_last_run() is just one of the many functions available on the Dag object.  Here's where I found it: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3396

You can also tweak the formatting of the string for the date format, and what you want output if there is no previous run.

Comment: dag.get_last_dagrun(include_externally_triggered=True) is for externally triggering dags

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own user custom macro function, use airflow model to search meta-database.

```
def get_last_dag_run(dag_id):
  //TODO search DB
  return xxx

dag = DAG(
    'example',
    schedule_interval='0 1 * * *',
    user_defined_macros={
        'last_dag_run_execution_date': get_last_dag_run,
    }
)
```

Then use the KEY in your template.

Comment: This answer seems to only answer one half, omitting the DB search.