# Getting the date of the most recent successful DAG execution

Tags: airflow

I am looking to create a transform in Airflow, and I want to ensure to get all data from my source since the last time a DAG has run in order to update my target table. In order to this, I want to be able to get the most recent execution which was successful.

I have found this: [Apache airflow macro to get last dag run execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923684/apache-airflow-macro-to-get-last-dag-run-execution-time) which gets me somewhere to the end goal, however, this only gets the last time the DAG executed, regardless of it being successful or not.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM schema.table
WHERE table.updated_at > '{{ last_dag_run_execution_date(dag) }}';
```

If an execution fails (due to connectivity or something like), the last_dag_run_execution_date(dag) will update, but we've missed the execution for that previous DAG run.

Ideally, this will pull the most recent non-failed execution. Or if anyone has any ideas how I can meet this, please let me know

Comment: For readers of this question, also worth checking **[1]** [Apache airflow macro to get last dag run execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51923684/3679900), **[2]** [How to get last two successful execution dates of Airflow job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61671646/3679900) or this [search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+get+last+execution+date+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ended up changing the function in the referenced question to use the latest_execution_date, which is a predefined macro in Airflow, as such:

```
def get_last_dag_run(dag):
    last_dag_run = dag.latest_execution_date
    if last_dag_run is None: 
        return '2013-01-01'
    else:
        return last_dag_run
```

Seems to be working for me at the moment.

Comment: Is return showing both dag name and last execution date ?