# How to get last two successful execution dates of Airflow job?

Tags: airflow

I need to get last two successful execution dates of Airflow job to use in my current run.
Example :
Execution date  Job status
2020-05-03      success 
2020-05-04      fail
2020-05-05      success

Question :
When I run my job on May 6th I should get values of May 3rd and 5th into variables. Is it possible?

Comment: For readers of this question, also worth checking **[1]** [Apache airflow macro to get last dag run execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51923684/3679900), **[2]** [Getting the date of the most recent successful DAG execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607042/3679900) or this [search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+get+last+execution+date+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 5):

You can leverage `SQLAlchemy` magic for retrieving `execution_date`s against last 'n' successfull runs

```
from pendulum import Pendulum
from typing import List, Dict, Any, Optional
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.settings import Session
from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance

def last_execution_date(
    dag_id: str, task_id: str, n: int, session: Optional[Session] = None
) -> List[Pendulum]:
    """
    This function is to queries against airflow table and
    return the most recent execution date
    Args:
        dag_id: dag name
        task_id : task name
        n : number of runs
        session: Session to connect airflow postgres db
    Returns:
        list of execution date of most of recent n runs
    """
    query_val = (
        session.query(TaskInstance)
        .filter(
            TaskInstance.dag_id == dag_id,
            TaskInstance.task_id == task_id,
            TaskInstance.state == State.SUCCESS,
        )
        .order_by(TaskInstance.execution_date.desc())
        .limit(n)
    )
    execution_dates: List[Pendulum] = list(map(lambda ti: ti.execution_date, query_val))
    return execution_dates

# Above function can be used as utility function and can be leveraged with provide_session as below:
 
last_success_date_fn = provide_session(last_execution_date) # can use provide session decorator as is.
```

This snippet is tested end to end and can be used in prod.

I've referred to [`tree()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L1398) of [`views.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py) for coming up with this script.

---

Alternatively, you can fire this SQL query to the Airflow's meta-db to retrieve last n execution dates with successful runs

```
SELECT execution_date
FROM task_instance
WHERE dag_id = 'my_dag_id'
  AND task_id = 'my_task_id'
  AND state = 'success'
ORDER BY execution_date DESC
LIMIT n
```

Comment: I tried to run the above piece of code but It seems to generate a query that has a syntax error in this place `ORDER BY
        EXISTS
        (
                SELECT
                        1
                FROM
                        dag_run
                WHERE
                        dag_run.dag_id = task_instance.dag_id
                AND     dag_run.run_id = task_instance.run_id
                AND     dag_run.execution_date 
    DESC
  ) `
What should be the solution of such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a syntax error in the generated queries from these examples, I managed to get this working using the following:

```py
def last_execution_date(
    dag_id: str, task_id: str, n: int):
    session = Session()
    query_val = (
        session.query(TaskInstance)
        .filter(
            TaskInstance.dag_id == dag_id,
            TaskInstance.task_id == task_id,
            TaskInstance.state == State.SUCCESS,
        )
        .order_by(TaskInstance.end_date.desc())
        .limit(n)
    )
    execution_dates = list(map(lambda ti: ti.execution_date, query_val))
    return execution_dates
```

The problem with ordering on `execution_date` is that it necessitates a join to the `DagRun` model to pick up `execution_date`. I have ordered by a column present on the `TaskInstance` model. This code makes the assumption that all tasks with a state of `state.SUCCESS` will have an `end_date`, and that the `end_date` will accurately order the tasks in execution order.

Also this script can help determine what underlying SQL will be run - this can be run in a local/virtualenv with Airflow installed:

```py
from airflow.settings import Session
from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun

session=Session()

query_val = (
    session.query(TaskInstance)
        .filter(
            TaskInstance.dag_id == 'foo'
        ) 
        .order_by(TaskInstance.end_date.desc())
)

print(str(query_val))
```

Which at the time of writing in Airflow 2.5.1 returns (formatted for readability):

```
SELECT
    task_instance.try_number AS task_instance_try_number,
    task_instance.task_id AS task_instance_task_id,
    task_instance.dag_id AS task_instance_dag_id,
    task_instance.run_id AS task_instance_run_id,
    task_instance.map_index AS task_instance_map_index,
    task_instance.start_date AS task_instance_start_date,
    task_instance.end_date AS task_instance_end_date,
    task_instance.duration AS task_instance_duration,
    task_instance.state AS task_instance_state,
    task_instance.max_tries AS task_instance_max_tries,
    task_instance.hostname AS task_instance_hostname,
    task_instance.unixname AS task_instance_unixname,
    task_instance.job_id AS task_instance_job_id,
    task_instance.pool AS task_instance_pool,
    task_instance.pool_slots AS task_instance_pool_slots,
    task_instance.queue AS task_instance_queue,
    task_instance.priority_weight AS task_instance_priority_weight,
    task_instance.operator AS task_instance_operator,
    task_instance.queued_dttm AS task_instance_queued_dttm,
    task_instance.queued_by_job_id AS task_instance_queued_by_job_id,
    task_instance.pid AS task_instance_pid,
    task_instance.executor_config AS task_instance_executor_config,
    task_instance.updated_at AS task_instance_updated_at,
    task_instance.external_executor_id AS task_instance_external_executor_id,
    task_instance.trigger_id AS task_instance_trigger_id,
    task_instance.trigger_timeout AS task_instance_trigger_timeout,
    task_instance.next_method AS task_instance_next_method,
    task_instance.next_kwargs AS task_instance_next_kwargs,
    dag_run_1.state AS dag_run_1_state,
    dag_run_1.id AS dag_run_1_id,
    dag_run_1.dag_id AS dag_run_1_dag_id,
    dag_run_1.queued_at AS dag_run_1_queued_at,
    dag_run_1.execution_date AS dag_run_1_execution_date,
    dag_run_1.start_date AS dag_run_1_start_date,
    dag_run_1.end_date AS dag_run_1_end_date,
    dag_run_1.run_id AS dag_run_1_run_id,
    dag_run_1.creating_job_id AS dag_run_1_creating_job_id,
    dag_run_1.external_trigger AS dag_run_1_external_trigger,
    dag_run_1.run_type AS dag_run_1_run_type,
    dag_run_1.conf AS dag_run_1_conf,
    dag_run_1.data_interval_start AS dag_run_1_data_interval_start,
    dag_run_1.data_interval_end AS dag_run_1_data_interval_end,
    dag_run_1.last_scheduling_decision AS dag_run_1_last_scheduling_decision,
    dag_run_1.dag_hash AS dag_run_1_dag_hash,
    dag_run_1.log_template_id AS dag_run_1_log_template_id,
    dag_run_1.updated_at AS dag_run_1_updated_at
FROM
    task_instance
    JOIN dag_run AS dag_run_1 ON dag_run_1.dag_id = task_instance.dag_id
    AND dag_run_1.run_id = task_instance.run_id
WHERE
    task_instance.dag_id = ?
ORDER BY
    task_instance.end_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In the lastest version of airflow:

```py
def last_execution_date(
    dag_id: str, task_id: str, n: int):
    session = Session()
    query_val = (
        session.query(TaskInstance)
        .filter(
            TaskInstance.dag_id == dag_id,
            TaskInstance.task_id == task_id,
            TaskInstance.state == State.SUCCESS,
        )
        .order_by(TaskInstance.execution_date.desc())
        .limit(n)
    )
    execution_dates = list(map(lambda ti: ti.execution_date, query_val))
    return execution_dates
```