# Is it possible to obtain the time of the last successful dag run?

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow, I'm trying to write a dag that checks for updated records in a table and adds them to a history table. I'd like to get the time of the last successful dagrun. That way, I can capture any updates that occurred since the last successful update. I see that there's a `latest_execution_date` method available for dags (as well as the `prev_execution_date` macro), however if I used this I could still miss updates that occurred during a previous dag's run if it failed. Is there any way for me to access the time of the most recent successful dag run within a dag?

Comment: If that provides the time of the last successful execution date, then yes. But if the latest dagrun is a failure, is that what the function returns?

Comment: that is also answered in [How to get last two successful execution dates of Airflow job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61671646/3679900)