# how to get latest execution time of a dag run in airflow

Tags: airflow

I tried below code but still i am getting issue

```
from airflow.models DagModel

def get_latest_execution_date(**kwargs):

session = airflow.settings.Session()

f = open("/home/Insurance/InsuranceDagsTimestamp.txt","w+")

try:
    Insurance_last_dag_run = session.query(DagModel)
    for Insdgrun in Insurance_last_dag_run:
        if Insdgrun is None: 
            f.write(Insdgrun.dag_id+",9999-12-31"+"\n")
        else:
            f.write(Insdgrun.dag_id+","+ Insdgrun.execution_date+"\n")
except:
    session.rollback()
finally:
    session.close()

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='records',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_latest_execution_date,
    dag=dag)
```

Is there any way how to fix and get the latest dag run time information

Comment: A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+get+last+execution+date+site:stackoverflow.com) returns some results of which **(1)** [Apache airflow macro to get last dag run execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51923684/3679900), **(2)** [Getting the date of the most recent successful DAG execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607042/3679900) and **(3)** [How to get last two successful execution dates of Airflow job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61671646/3679900) appear applicable to your problem. Also please elaborate `"..but still i am getting issue.."`

Comment: @y2k-shubham .. Thnks for the reply , i am getting invalid function "get_last_dag_run"..

Comment: and i am trying to get all the dags not any specific dag

Comment: @y2k-shubham .. Can you pls help me with suggestion which module i need to import to get the last success execution date of the dag , i tried dag model but i didnt get

Comment: (assuming you are going to run this script through some task / operator) you need to use [dag *property* from task](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ac943c9e18f75259d531dbda8c51e650f57faa4c/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L611): `my_task.dag`, where `my_task` is a reference to your task / operator (in a custom operator, you could use `self`)

Comment: @y2k-shubham .. I pasted my code. If possible can you please have a look and suggest pls for changes

Comment: @ Can any one pls help with this question..

Answer (score 13):

There are multiple ways to get the most recent execution of a DagRun. One way is to make use of the Airflow DagRun model.

```py
from airflow.models import DagRun

def get_most_recent_dag_run(dag_id):
    dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
    dag_runs.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=True)
    return dag_runs[0] if dag_runs else None


dag_run = get_most_recent_dag_run('fake-dag-id-001')
if dag_run:
    print(f'The most recent DagRun was executed at: {dag_run.execution_date}')
```

You can find more info on the DagRun model and it's properties in the [Airflow Docs located here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `PythonOperator` `op_args` parameter is templatized.

The callable only writes the latest execution date to a file so you can implement the function the following way:

```py
def store_last_execution_date(execution_date):
    '''Appends latest execution date to a file
    :param execution_date: The last execution date of the DagRun.
    '''

    with open("/home/Insurance/InsuranceDagsTimestamp.txt", "w+") as f:
        f.write(execution_date)


t1 = PythonOperator(
         task_id="records",
         provide_context=True,
         python_callable=store_last_execution_date,
         op_args=[
             "{{dag.get_latest_execution_date()}}",
         ],
         dag=dag
     )
```

Comment: Tried the exact same snippet and it does not work!

Comment: with Airflow >=1.10.6 you can use macros in templates. Just replace "{{dag.get_latest_execution_date()}}" with "{{ prev_execution_date }}" 
Note- two space between text and opening closing curly braces are important.
Reference to Airflow docs:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/macros.html?highlight=prev_execution_date