# Get session parameter for airflow.models.dag get_last_dagrun()

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to pass into my custom Operator a parameter which is the last run time of the dag itself.

Following the documentation, I understand that i should use `dag.get_last_dagrun()` https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.get_last_dagrun . However, I can't manage to pass the session parameter correctly.
Where can I find this?

When using the function without parameters, it return `None`.
I think that it's because I triggered the Dag myself, thus i want to set `include_externally_triggered` to true. But i still need to manage the session parameter before.

I tried to create the variable `last_run` before creating the dag and also when defining the tasks. I suppose that inside the task, self is included and it will fetch correctly without putting any parameters.
But what about the one which is outside of the dag?

I have also tried this solution which give me a time even if its the first time I run the Dag (I have clean the dag log from the ui), Maybe its the current executing DAG timestamp? If yes, I would need to compare the dates to exempt if equal?. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63930004/18036486

```py
from airflow import DAG
from DAG.operators.custom_operator1 import customOperator1

last_run = dag.get_last_dagrun() #HERE

default_args = {
    "owner": "admin",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email": ["email@email.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="Custom",
    schedule_interval="@once",
    description="Desc",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 3, 11),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["custom"],
    default_args=default_args) as dag:

    #Custom Operator
    custom = customOperator1(
      task_id = 'custom',
      last_run = dag.get_last_dagrun() # OR HERE
    )

custom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63930004/18036486 : . is including the current running Dag. Therefore, i slightly modified the function in order to exempt other dags which status isn't 'running' of course, you can add other conditions for the other Dag states:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhbBd.png)

Now, I can get the lastest successfull Dag execution_date to dynamically update my data!

```py
from airflow.models import DagRun

def get_last_exec_date(dag_id):
    dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
    dags = []
    for dag in dag_runs:
        if dag.state == 'success':
            dags.append(dag)
    
    dags.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=False)

    return dags[0] if dags != [] else None
```