# Airflow default variables - Incremental load setup

Tags: macros, airflow

I am trying to implement a incremental data load for a data extract from rds postgres to another postgres rds

I am using airflow, to implement the ETL. So, after reading for a while about airflow macros, I decided I'll set up the incremental flow with airflow default variables.

So, the algorithm is this way,

if my previous execution date is None or null or '':
pick data from the beginning of time(in our case its a year back)
else
pick the previous execution date
end if

Note : the following code is to understand default variables at first, and this is not yet implemented to the problem I have mentioned above

The corresponding code for that is as shown below. When I run the dag for the first time, I always end up printing 'None' for previoussuccessfulexecutiondate variable and never the historical date like what I have mentioned. I am unable to figure this out. Any ideas on this would be of great help

```
from datetime import *
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args={'owner':'airflow','start_date': days_ago(1),'depends_on_past':'False'}


dag = DAG('jinja_trial_10',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5))



def printexecutiontimes(**kwargs):
    executiondate = kwargs.get('execution_date')
    previoussuccessfulexecutiondate =  kwargs.get('prev_execution_date_success')
    previousexecutiondate = kwargs.get('prev_ds_nodash')

    if (previoussuccessfulexecutiondate == 'None' or previoussuccessfulexecutiondate is None):
        previoussuccessfulexecutiondate = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 365),'%Y-%m-%d')


    print('Execution Date : {0}'.format(executiondate))
    print('Previous successful execution date : {0}'.format(previoussuccessfulexecutiondate))
    print('Previous execution date : {0}'.format(previousexecutiondate))


    print('hello')




task_start  = DummyOperator(task_id = 'start',dag=dag)

jinja_task= PythonOperator(task_id = 'TryingoutJinjatemplates',
                           python_callable =printexecutiontimes,
                           provide_context = 'True',
                           dag=dag )

task_end = DummyOperator(task_id = 'end',dag=dag)


task_start >>jinja_task >> task_end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to something very similar recently and following code is what i have ended up creating a custom function using DagRun details.

[Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936353/11513936) - if you just want to get last DAG run (irrespective of status).

For me, i had to get the last date of successful run, hence created below function:

```
def get_last_dag_run(dag_id):
    dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
    dag_runs.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=True)

    for dag_run in dag_runs:
        #print all dag runs - debug only
        print(f"All ----- state: {dag_run.state} , run_id: {dag_run.run_id} , execution_date: {dag_run.execution_date}")

    print('Success runs ---------------------------------')
    dag_runs = list(filter(lambda x: x.state == 'success', dag_runs))
    for dag_run in dag_runs:
        #print successfull dag runs - debug only
        print(f"Success - state: {dag_run.state} , run_id: {dag_run.run_id} , execution_date: {dag_run.execution_date}")
    
    # return last execution run or default value (01-01-1970) 
    return dag_runs[0].execution_date if dag_runs else datetime(1970, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sharif. But, while I try your solution, can you help me understand why my code did not work?

Comment: No idea, here are few more SO links you can refer, most of them ended up writing a custom code.
https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+get+last+execution+date+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Here is the answer:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#why-next-ds-or-prev-ds-might-not-contain-expected-values

Comment: hi Sharif, I did use the logic in the stackoverflow link(anserwed by Charlie)  you have provided. However, my understanding is the first time a dag runs, and according to Charlie's logic, I must get 'no prev runs'. But I never get it, I always get a date. My expectation is I must get 'no prev runs', so that I can pass the correct dates to pick the incremental data

Comment: so, what I see is, when I check the type of last_dag_run from Charlie's solution and type of previoussuccessfulexecutiondate from my code, it says, <type - proxy>. And a check with 'is None' , does not work on it...

Answer (score 0):

After a few experiments and a lot of reading, I came up with the following code and it worked for me

- Create a variable in Airflow UI and assign it a value 0
- Use Airflow’s predefined variables, to determine whether it is a full
  load or a incremental load
- Pseudo code -

```
If
    value of Variable created = 0
then 
    set Variable = 1
    set the start data to point in time in the past(a date-time from the inception of a certain process)
    set the end date to the value of the "execution_date" (defined as a part of airflow's predefined variables)
else
    set the start date to "prev_execution_date_success" (defined as a part of airflow's predefined variables)
    set the end date to "execution_date" (defined as a part of airflow's predefined variables)
end
```

Below is the code snippet for the same

```py
from datetime import *
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.models import Variable

default_args={'owner':'airflow','start_date': datetime(2020,11,3,12,5),'depends_on_past':'False'}


dag = DAG('airflow_incremental_load_setup',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5))

def printexecutiontimes(**kwargs):
    # Variable to be created before the running of dag
    full_load_check = Variable.get('full_load_completion')
    print('full_load_check : {0}'.format(full_load_check))
    if full_load_check == '0':
        print('First execution')
        print('Execution date : {0}'.format(kwargs.get('execution_date')))
        print('Actual start date : {0}'.format(kwargs.get('ds')))
        print('Previous successful execution date : {0}'.format(kwargs.get('prev_execution_date_success')))
        print('Calculated field : {0}'.format(datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365), '%Y-%m-%d')))
        Variable.set('full_load_check', '1')
        start_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365), '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date = datetime.strftime(kwargs.get('execution_date'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    else:
        print('After the first execution ..')
        print('Execution date : {0}'.format(kwargs.get('execution_date')))
        print('Actual start date : {0}'.format(kwargs.get('ds')))
        print('Previous successful execution date : {0}'.format(kwargs.get('prev_execution_date_success')))
        print('Calculated field : {0}'.format(kwargs.get('prev_execution_date_success')))
        start_date = kwargs.get('prev_execution_date_success')
        start_date = parse(str(start_date))
        end_date = kwargs.get('execution_date')
        end_date = parse(str(end_date))
        print('Type of start_date_check : {0}'.format(type(start_date)))
        start_date = datetime.strftime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date = datetime.strftime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

task_start  = DummyOperator(task_id = 'start',dag=dag)

main_task= PythonOperator(task_id = 'IncrementalJobTask',
                            python_callable =printexecutiontimes,
                            provide_context = 'True',
                            dag=dag )

task_end = DummyOperator(task_id = 'end',dag=dag)


task_start >>main_task >> task_end
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

```
if isinstance(context['prev_execution_date_success'], type(None)):
```